Pocketbase change user email
In my React project I have written a function to change user's email address with Pocketbase, but when I type the currently used email it works, when I type a new email it gives an error.
I mention the given error below
const changeEmail = async (data) => {
        try {
            const record = await pb.collection('users').update(pb.authStore.model.id, data);
            toast.success("Your e-mail changed successfully");
            console.log(pb.authStore.model.id, record)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(data)
            toast.error(e.message);
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

const {changeEmail} = RegisterFunctions();

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        await changeEmail(data);

    }
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">
                                    Email
                                </label>
                                <input type="email" defaultValue={pb.authStore.model.email} className={"form-control"}
                                       id={"email"} {...register("email")} />
                            </div>
                            <button type={"submit"} className="btn btn-blue">Update</button>
                        </form>

ClientResponseError 400: Something went wrong while processing your request.
    at pocketbase.js?v=dabdfdd8:889:13
    at async changeEmail (register.js:42:28)
    at async onSubmit (Dashboard.jsx?t=1713254037468:22:9)
    at async react-hook-form.js?v=dabdfdd8:1629:9


Instead of update
const record = await pb.collection('users').update(pb.authStore.model.id, data);

you should use requestEmailChange
const record = await pb.collection('users').requestEmailChange(data);

